# Will adding an index to a column improve the select query (without where) performance in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance, query-performance

I have a MySQL table that contains 20 000 000 rows, and columns like (user_id, registered_timestamp, etc). I have written a below query to get a count of users registered day wise. The query was taking a long time to execute. Will adding an index to the registered_timestamp column improve the execution time?

```
select date(registered_timestamp), count(userid) from table group by 1
```

Comment: What is a "cr"?

Comment: No. An index will not help.

Comment: No.  That index would not help this query.  You can review the rules for optimizing `group by` in the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html.

Comment: Ah... a "cr" is called a "crore". It means 10 million.

Comment: Your query does not have a filtering condition. You are reading all the rows of the table. A "covering index" may [marginally] improve the performance of your query, it's not much that you can do. I assume this is for a batch processing (at night), since this query is not suitable for interactive response to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this query to get a list of dates and the number of registrations on each date.

```
 SELECT date(registered_timestamp) date, COUNT(*) 
   FROM table
  GROUP BY date(registered_timestamp)
```

Then an index on `table(registered_timestamp)` will help a little because it's a covering index.

If you adapt your query to return dates from a limited range, for example.

```
 SELECT date(registered_timestamp) date, COUNT(*) 
   FROM table
  WHERE registered_timestamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY
    AND registered_timestamp < CURDATE() 
  GROUP BY date(registered_timestamp)
```

the index will help.  (This query returns results for the week ending yesterday.) However, the index will not help this query.

```
 SELECT date(registered_timestamp) date, COUNT(*) 
   FROM table
  WHERE DATE(registered_timestamp) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY /* slow! */
  GROUP BY date(registered_timestamp)
```

because the function on the column makes the query [unsargeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

You probably can address this performance issue with a MySQL generated column.  This command:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
       ADD registered_date DATE 
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS DATE(registered_timestamp)
       STORED;
```

Then you can add an index on the generated column

```
CREATE INDEX regdate ON `table` ( registered_date );
```

Then you can use that generated (derived) column in your query, and get a lot of help from that index.

```
 SELECT registered_date, COUNT(*) 
   FROM table
  GROUP BY registered_date;
```

But beware, creating the generated column and its index will take a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date(registered_timestamp), count(userid) from table group by 1
```

Would benefit from `INDEX(registered_timestamp, userid)` but only because such an index is "covering".  The query will still need to read every row of the index, and do a filesort.

If `userid` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, then this would give you the same answers without bothering to check each `userid` for being `NOT NULL`.

```
select date(registered_timestamp), count(*) from table group by 1
```

And `INDEX(registered_timestamp)` would be equivalent to the above suggestion.  (This is because InnoDB implicitly tacks on the PK.)

If this query is common, then you could build and maintain a "summary table", which collects the count every night for the day's registrations.  Then the query would be a much faster fetch from that smaller table.